# network connection suddenly disconnected and disabled during large file transfer over the network

Tags: windows-8, ethernet, network-adapter, broadcom

I am currently using windows 8.1 64 bit on my laptop.

I have a working network setup and I can start to transfer some large (20+GB) files.  However after a few minutes the network connection suddenly disconnects. The Ethernet port suddenly becomes disabled and can no longer be enabled until I reboot. (The first obvious symptom I see is that the file transfer suddenly stops).

This happens every time. How can I fix this?

Comment: You wrote "I am CURRENTLY using windows 8.1". Did this problem start after you changed or upgraded the OS or changed or upgraded the network drivers?

Comment: Whether the destination system has Fat 32 file system, if so then it can't take files more than 4GB. Not sure that can cause network to go down. Whether the network goes down on both machines?

Comment: yes, i recently changed my OS to windows 8.1 my NIC is Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet. I haven't installed a driver yet and I'm still looking for one. The network connection was working so i thought i don't need to install any drivers.

Comment: Are there any errors logged in the event log? (You can start it via [Start] [run] `eventvwr.msc` on windows 7. No experience with windows 8 yet, but I suspect it is the same).

Comment: @Chandrasekar In most cases (as in, everything up to windows 7) it will fail to write beyond 4GB. it will not cause the NIC to fail.

Comment: no errors were reported. the network status just suddenly becomes disabled.

Comment: i only found a driver for windows 7 64bit. will that work with windows 8.1 64bit?

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any driver, firmware, or bios updates for your laptop, remote/destination system(s), and intermediate; in that order, from Microsoft and equipment manufacturers.  Also, have you tried forcing your network adapter to specific port speeds?  Also try switching out the intermediate just to rule it out.

Comment: First try driver updates from the laptop manufacturer, then from Broadcom.  The broadcom driver may not work, and you will have to reload the driver from you laptop manufacturer.  Also, perhaps try the same sort of file transfer with a Linux live cd system--that could help you isolate whether it is a hardware or software/driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the filesize. What you experiencing is that the driver itself is crashing under heavy load.

You need to uninstall the network driver first, then install it again and then reboot to fix the issue.

Before you uninstall your network driver, make sure you download the latest drivers first (once uninstalled, you won't have a working network, so you can't download it then without going through a lot of trouble).

*You can safely install the downloaded drivers without uninstalling it first to test that the drivers will install okay.*

Note to uninstall the network driver, do the following:

```
1. Open your device manager.
2. Locate your network card.
3. Right click and choose uninstall.
4. Restart the computer.
```

Seen this happen before, and this method fixed it. Hope it does for you as well.

EDIT: I see you haven't actually installed the network driver, so you are using a stock driver, which obviously isn't working well. You might get it fixed by just installing the right driver. To find the proper driver, just search for `brand of laptop` `type of laptop` `drivers` `windows 8`.

For example:

```
hp probook 4030 drivers windows 8
```